# Changing background colour for the Selected Tab

Tags: android, layout, textview

[image]

This is my Screen layout, and i want to do this, when I clicked on Popular tab, then Popular block should turns Blue.

Same for the Price, Time and Duration tab.

I've tried to do with Linear Layout but it doesn't.

i have taken it in Text View, and the vertical and Horizontal Lines are used using View tag and I have not use TabLayout, just to make it simple I just used TextView With Background.

Please suggest me a proper solution with code if you can.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Comment: in xml of tablayout, add  app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"

Comment: I have used TextView in LinearLayout Bro.. its Not TabLayout

Comment: then when click on textview chage color of that textview .

Comment: You didn't get my question buddy, I dont want to change textView Colour I want to change that Popular SQUARE box in which popular is placed turns blue when clicked.

Comment: "I have used TextView in LinearLayout Bro.. its Not TabLayout" - Don't you think that might be worth mentioning _in the question_?

Comment: yes, that SQUARE is textview right? so you want to chnage its background color to blue

Comment: Yes, u got it..

Comment: i post some code after some time.

Comment: Sure, I will wait for it.

Comment: @Mike I have mentioned it in my question, so please ask before down Voting

Comment: No, you have not. Nowhere do you say you're not using `TabLayout`, and your description is terrible. Furthermore, we shouldn't have to ask about your setup. You have all the time in the world to make the question as clear as possible before you post it. If you don't like downvotes, then write better questions.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file add following line in your TabLayout,

```
app:tabBackground="#0000FA"
```

by this you can chage color of selected tab.

If you have used TextView then just simply create or add this method to you java file & call it from each textviews onclick event by passing the textview to it.

```
public void changeTabColor(TextView tvSelected){
  tv1.setBackgroundColor(Color.White);
  tv2.setBackgroundColor(Color.White);
  tv3.setBackgroundColor(Color.White);

  tvSelected.setBackgroundColor(Color.Blue);
}
```

Comment: Let me try it buddy.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.popular_tab:
             ResetTabColor();
             popular_tab.setBackgroundColor(Color.blue);
        case //Do the rest with other tab
    }
}

private void ResetTabColor(){
popular_tab.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); // or white color
time_tab.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
duration_tab.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
price_tab.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```